# Permission denied on download with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, download, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get objects in my bucket on Google Cloud Storage. 
To do so I use the recommended code by Google on its API pages :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-php

But when I do, I got a permission denied error.

I configured Composer with the permission (for example my code to list the objects within the bucket works fine) but I can't download anything. I get this error :

Warning: fopen(C:\wamp64\www\test): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\google\cloud-storage\src\StorageObject.php on line 602

I gave myself all the permissions to in the Cloud Storage console but the error still appear.

I also wondered, is it possible to get/copy the content of the object without downloading it?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT : The code is pretty simple :

```
$storage = new StorageClient($config = [ 
    'keyFilePath' => "[PATH OF MY KEYFILE]",
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->object($objectName);
$object->downloadToFile($destination);
printf('Downloaded gs://%s/%s to %s' . PHP_EOL,
    $bucketName, $objectName, basename($destination));
```

}

In the storage I just have buckets with a list of object and I need to get the content/dl one of them to merge it with another Json

Comment: It might be useful to see more of the design / implementation of the logic you are using to access the data.   Also, have a look at Stackdriver logging.  This is where all the GCP log entries go which might shed some light on the nature of the error.

Comment: I edited my question ! I'll check my GCP log entries

Comment: There is no error entry in the Stackdriver, the denial of permission isn't represented. Or I don't know where to look

Comment: Looking a the docs, I am guessing the eror is occuring at the downloadToFile call?  I see that takes a local path on your local file system where the file is stored.  What is he value of $destination in your story?  Do you have write permissions?

Comment: Indeed it's the downloadToFile call that fails ! The destination is a local folder in my local system. I expected this code to create the file and fill it, in fact I just need to read the content of the object to append it to another (already created) file. How should I do to allow the write in file? Should I create the file and expect this code to fill it?

Comment: My gut is saying that you have an application.  That application is trying to write data to a new file on your file system.  It feels from the information presented that the directory into which you are writing is C:\wamp64\www\test.  It appears that your application doesn't have permissions to write there.

Comment: Yeah you're right, last thing, do you know how can i modify the write permission of my application?

Comment: Sadly I'm not that skilled on Windows file systems.  What I'd suggest is to google around and read on the subject.  At the highest level, you'll probably need to know the identity that your application is attempting to "write as" and then set the directory permission on the target directory to allow "that" identity to have permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

To make individual objects publicly readable:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

Verify the next code:

function download_object($bucketName, $objectName, $destination)

{

```
$storage = new StorageClient();

$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);

$object = $bucket->object($objectName);

$object->downloadToFile($destination);

printf('Downloaded gs://%s/%s to %s' . PHP_EOL,
    $bucketName, $objectName, basename($destination));
```

}

Comment: Thank you ! But the access to all my objects is already public. The permission is still denied

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION] I couldn't download the object outside of the folder where the PHP code is. 
Destination needs to be **DIR** . '/my-file.json'

Thank you all